# count subcategory of current category in magento

Tags: magento, if-statement, categories

magento,in if statement im using a condition for two option, first one is current category has zero sub category and second one is current category has more than zero subcategory, but this condition is not working with this code

```
       <?php $helper = $this->helper('catalog/category') ?>
       <?php $categories = $this->getStoreCategories() ?>
       <?php if (count($categories) > 0): ?>
             <?php $_filters = $this->getFilters() ?>
        <?php foreach ($_filters as $_filter): ?>

                   <?php if($_filter->getName() == 'Brand' || $_filter->getName() == 'Category' || $_filter->getName() == 'Store' || $_filter->getName() == 'Price' ): ?>   
                          <?php if($_filter->getItemsCount()): ?>
                               <dt><div style="background-color:#cdcdcd;padding:4px;border-radius:3px;"><?php echo $this->__($_filter->getName()) ?></div></dt>
                               <dd><div style="max-height:150px;overflow:auto;padding-top:5px;"><?php echo $_filter->getHtml() ?></div></dd>
                           <?php endif; ?>
                   <?php endif; ?>

        <?php endforeach; ?>
      <?php else : ?>
         <?php $_filters = $this->getFilters() ?>
            <?php foreach ($_filters as $_filter): ?>
            <?php if($_filter->getItemsCount()): ?>
                <dt>
        <div style="background-color:#cdcdcd;padding:4px;border-radius:3px;"><?php echo $this->__($_filter->getName()) ?></div>
                    <?php if ($removeUrl = Mage::helper('layerednavigation')->getRemoveUrl($_filter)): ?>
                        <a class="btn-remove" href="<?php echo $removeUrl ?>" title="<?php echo $this->__('Clear All') ?>"><?php echo $this->__('Clear All') ?></a>
                    <?php endif ?>
                </dt>
                <dd><div style="max-height:150px;overflow:auto;padding-top:5px;"><?php echo $_filter->getHtml() ?></div></dd>
            <?php endif; ?>
            <?php endforeach; ?>
       <?php endif; ?>
        </dl>
        <script type="text/javascript">decorateDataList('narrow-by-list')</script>
    <?php endif; ?>
```

ckeck its first statement and give me solution

Answer (score 0):

Hello check below code may be help you

```
<?php
$layer = Mage::getSingleton('catalog/layer');
$_category = $layer->getCurrentCategory();
$currentCategoryId= $_category->getId();
$children = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->getCategories($currentCategoryId);
$countSubcategory=0;
foreach ($children as $category)
    {
       $countSubcategory++;   
    }
echo $countSubcategory;
?>
```

Comment: This code shows 2 more categories then the total number of categories can you please suggest another solution.